# Angular : ngOnChanges is not detecting changes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've a **dropdown list** in **one component**. Each time the value of dropdown changes I'm trying to detect the **changed value** in **another component**. But I've a strange problem. Sometimes, when I change the value of dropdown it's triggering the ngOnChanges and sometimes not. Idk why.

This is my code:

**AppComp**

**html**

```
    <td width="20%" class="cursor">
      <select (change)="changedvalue($event)" class="form-control" name="level">
        <option  hidden selected> -- Select options -- </option>
        <option>Level 1</option>
        <option>Level 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>

   <td class="cursor">
     <app-other-comp [group]="group"></app-other-comp>
   </td>
```

**ts**

```
group: string;

changedvalue(event: Event) {
   const value = (<HTMLSelectElement>event.target).value;
   this.group = value;
   console.log('From AppComp' + this.group);
  }
```

**OtherComp**

**ts**

```
@Input() group: string;

ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('Changed : ' + this.group);
  }
```

As in the browser console you can see sometimes it detects a change and sometimes it does not.

**change doesn't get detected:**

[image]

**change gets detected:**

[image]

Comment: Can you point the scenarios where it gets detected vs when it doesn't? Or does it happen completely at random? Is there any pattern you can observe?

Comment: Added your code to StackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-53518539) and the problem doesn't happens

Comment: @LloydFrancis I notcied that after the intilization of the the component if I chage the value it doesn't work but after that it starts workings, so means first time it doesn't work but after it works

Comment: @Junaid did you check the stackblitz link?

Answer (score -1):

change function is called when input blurred. you can use ngModel and ngModelChange function like this:

```
<td width="20%" class="cursor">
  <select (ngModelChange)="changedvalue($event)" [(ngModel)]="value"  class="form-control" name="level">
    <option  hidden selected> -- Select options -- </option>
    <option>Level 1</option>
    <option>Level 2</option>
  </select>
</td>

<td class="cursor">
 <app-other-comp [group]="group"></app-other-comp>
</td>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue. Please check the stackblitz link in the question. It works fine.